# How can I convert values stored in ANSI (Windows 1252) in a database to UTF-8

Tags: c#, sqlite, encoding, utf-8

When I open a legacy database in Sqlite Browser, the text is already displayed wrong. The only encoding I can set is UTF-8 and UTF-16.
[image: Sqlite browser with Umlaut]

When I query the database, the encoding is already wrong in Visual Studio.
[image: Visual Studio locals]

I assume the text is encoded in ANSI (Windows-1252) (*confirmed in the comments*). I tried converting it to UTF-8

```
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        byte[] encBytes = encoding.GetBytes(result);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(encoding, Encoding.UTF8, encBytes);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

but now the question mark symbol is just a question mark.
[image: Still wrong]

Somehow, the external legacy app displays it correctly, so there appears to be a way. But I'm not sure what I can try next.

Comment: If the original encoding is unknown to you, I suggest you use the command line sqlite3 tool to write the output of a query into a file.
Try MS Word and Notepad++ to detect the original encoding. Maybe that legacy app has an ini file or options dialog, where you can find that out.

Comment: I have a new idea. Using the command line tool sqlite3, you can dump the whole database as an sql file. If it shows the characters correctly, than you can change the encoding to UTF-8 in Notepad++. Once you have it in UTF-8, you can recreate the database with all the content in UTF-8.

Comment: @KağanKayal, I exported the contents and it does show Windows-1252 as encoding. I must use this database, so I can't encode the database differently.

Comment: FWIW: Importing the UTF-8 converted table into the db would work, but since it's auto generated, I can't do that in production.

Comment: Show the output of `SELECT hex(Article_Name) FROM ...` for one such row.

Comment: @CL. 416C752D4472656965636B7374`FC`747A6520352E3030206D (original) compared to 416C752D4472656965636B7374`C3BC`747A6520352E3030206D (utf-8 converted)

Comment: What type is `result`, and how are you reading it from the database?

Comment: Do you want to change the data in the database, or adjust your queries?

Comment: `result` is a `string`. I'm using Dapper to map the query to a list of `Article`, construct a `Json` object and use `result = o.toString()`. 

I can't change the data, so I need to work with the result or a different query.

Comment: ([Complete snippet](https://gist.github.com/SvenPetroll/6ff3eb97a985a2d5a237))

Comment: @Kağan Kaya: A windows command line won't show you utf8-characters correctly. It only shows question marks. You'll neeed a text-box in a windows application instead. Or you need to start cmd.exe with "/unicode", aka. cmd /K chcp 65001

Comment: @StefanSteiger: Indeed, I would not rely on the windows console to display the text correctly. But the sqlite3 tool can also redirect the output into a file as a wrote in my earlier comment. That must be correct. With an editor such as notepad++, you can then interpret the text in a desired encoding.

Comment: @Kağan Kayal 1: Interesting. Didn't know Notepad++ can do that. Probably not that hard to figure it out by trial and error. From my experience, most of the time it's either ASCII, ANSI (US/Western Europe), ISO-8859-1 [GetEncoding(28591)] , UTF7, UTF16, UTF32, or KOIR-8 [GetEncoding(20866)].

Comment: I have also converted the output in hex form "416C752D4472656965636B7374FC747A6520352E3030206D" to text and displayed it as windows-1252 encoding and can see the correct German expression. I then converted it to UTF-8 to be able to enter it here and you get "Alu-Dreieckstütze 5.00 m". So I can also confirm the original encoding is most likely windows-1252. But I can't rule out that some other encoding would fit as well.

Comment: @Sven: Just a warning: It seems that you are modernizing the interface to that database. If you have to stick to this database as it is, then you should also make sure that the new inputs and updates to it are in windows-1252 in future. Otherwise, you would end up in a big mess..

Comment: I'd guess that you need to specify the encoding when you open the connection to the database instead of trying to remove the corruption afterwards.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: That is my conclusion as well. Probably he didn't set the encoding in the connectionstring, and now it's taking ASCII...

Comment: @CodesInChaos There is no charset or encoding option in Sqlite that would fit the data though.

Comment: @Sven What about latin1 or ISO 8859-1? Those are very similar to Windows-1252.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem once,

John Skeet answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194019/correcting-text-in-database):

Basically take the string, get the bytes in the wrong encoding that it was encoded as, then get the string in the encoding that it really was:

```
string broken = "Brokers MÃ©xico, Intermediario de Aseguro,S.A."; // Get text from database
byte[] encoded = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(broken);
string corrected = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded);
```

So yours should simply be

```
string broken = "Whatever";
byte[] encoded = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(broken);
string corrected = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded);
```

Basically, now that you know that the re-conversion program is correct, I'd play around with the encodings mentioned here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding(v=vs.110).aspx
(just write a program that tests-through all the likely possibilities listed there, and see which pair will yield a match...)

If you know the source text, you could even perform the checking automagically:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public System.Data.DataTable dt;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        string correct = "Brokers México, Intermediario de Aseguro,S.A.";

        string broken = "Brokers MÃ©xico, Intermediario de Aseguro,S.A."; // Get text from database

        dt.Columns.Add("SourceEncoding", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("TargetEncoding", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("SourceEncodingName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("TargetEncodingName", typeof(string));

        // For reference
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding(v=vs.110).aspx
        int[] encs = new int[] { 
             20127 // US-ASCII
            ,28591 // iso-8859-1 Western European (ISO)       
            ,28592 // iso-8859-2 Central European (ISO)       
            ,28593 // iso-8859-3 Latin 3 (ISO)
            ,28594 // iso-8859-4 Baltic (ISO)
            ,28595 // iso-8859-5 Cyrillic (ISO)
            ,28596 // iso-8859-6 Arabic (ISO)
            ,28597 // iso-8859-7 Greek (ISO)
            ,28598 // iso-8859-8 Hebrew (ISO-Visual)          
            ,28599 // iso-8859-9 Turkish (ISO)
            ,28603 // iso-8859-13 Estonian (ISO)
            ,28605 // iso-8859-15 Latin 9 (ISO)   

            ,1250 // windows-1250 Central European (Windows)      
            ,1251 // windows-1251 Cyrillic (Windows)             
            ,1252 // Windows-1252 Western European (Windows)      
            ,1253 // windows-1253 Greek (Windows)                
            ,1254 // windows-1254 Turkish (Windows)              
            ,1255 // windows-1255 Hebrew (Windows)               
            ,1256 // windows-1256 Arabic (Windows)               
            ,1257 // windows-1257 Baltic (Windows)               
            ,1258 // windows-1258 Vietnamese (Windows)

            ,20866 // Cyrillic (KOI8-R)
            ,21866 // Cyrillic (KOI8-U)  

            ,65000 // UTF-7
            ,65001 // UTF-8
            ,1200 // UTF-16
            ,1201 // Unicode (Big-Endian)    

            ,12000 // UTF-32
            ,12001 // UTF-32BE (UTF-32 Big-Endian) 
        };


        for (int i = 0; i < encs.Length; ++i)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < encs.Length; ++j)
            {
                System.Data.DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                dr["SourceEncoding"] = encs[i];
                dr["TargetEncoding"] = encs[j];


                System.Text.Encoding enci = Encoding.GetEncoding(encs[i]);
                System.Text.Encoding encj = Encoding.GetEncoding(encs[j]);

                byte[] encoded = enci.GetBytes(broken);
                string corrected = encj.GetString(encoded);

                dr["Result"] = corrected;

                dr["SourceEncodingName"] = enci.BodyName;
                dr["TargetEncodingName"] = encj.BodyName;


                if (StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(correct, corrected))
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

        }

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Or even more thorough, just test all encodings:

```
private void btnTestAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    string correct = "Brokers México, Intermediario de Aseguro,S.A.";

    string broken = "Brokers MÃ©xico, Intermediario de Aseguro,S.A."; // Get text from database

    dt.Columns.Add("SourceEncoding", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TargetEncoding", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SourceEncodingName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("TargetEncodingName", typeof(string));



    System.Text.EncodingInfo[] encs = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings();

    for (int i = 0; i < encs.Length; ++i)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < encs.Length; ++j)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["SourceEncoding"] = encs[i].CodePage;
            dr["TargetEncoding"] = encs[j].CodePage;


            System.Text.Encoding enci = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(encs[i].CodePage);
            System.Text.Encoding encj = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(encs[j].CodePage);

            byte[] encoded = enci.GetBytes(broken);
            string corrected = encj.GetString(encoded);

            dr["Result"] = corrected;

            dr["SourceEncodingName"] = enci.BodyName;
            dr["TargetEncodingName"] = encj.BodyName;


            if (StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(correct, corrected))
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

    }

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

You can download the result [here](https://github.com/ststeiger/EncodingGuesser):

It's strange, it looks like you can get from German/ANSI (or ISO-8859-1) to ASCII, but there is NO WAY to convert it back (information loss)...

```
public static string lol()
{
    string source = "Alu-Dreieckstütze";

    // System.Text.Encoding encSource = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
    System.Text.Encoding encSource = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
    System.Text.Encoding encTarget = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;

    byte[] encoded = encSource.GetBytes(source);
    string broken = encTarget.GetString(encoded);

    return broken;
}
```

The funny thing is, since the legacy app displays it correctly, it can't have lost the information. 

So are you sure you haven't put a wrong (or no) encoding in the Sqlite connectionString ?

e.g.

```
  "Data Source=C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\location.db; Version=3; UseUTF16Encoding=True;Synchronous=Normal;New=False"; // set up the connection string
```

https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_any.html

It looks like you can test the encoding with [pragma encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532532/check-the-encoding-of-text-in-sqlite)

Comment: @Sven: You've had some funny convert between in addition to it. But if it doesn't work, you probably haven't found the right source and/or target encoding, because the code itselfs works. So what you can try next is playing with the codepages.

Comment: @StefanSteigerHi Stefan, thank you so much for your nice post and code. I have exactly the same problem :/ I have tested your code, but after clicking the button is the datagrid empty. How do you interpret it?

Answer (score 1):

2 steps:
First, you read the value from database as bytes array.
Second, you convert the bytes array with 1252 encoding into string.
Something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = dataReader["colomnName"];
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
string s = encoding.GetString(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also do get to import data from a source that encodes strings wrongly. But with the [Microsoft.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/) library it's quite easy to inject a user defined function to fix the encoding. I am also using [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) in that example:

```
using (var cnn = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={databasePath}")) {
    cnn.CreateFunction("fixencoding", (byte[] value) =>
        Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(value), isDeterministic: true);
    cnn.Open();
    return cnn.Query<Board>(Properties.Resources.GetBoards);
}
```

For this class:

```
public class Board
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set }
    public decimal Length { get; set; }
    public decimal Width { get; set; }
    public decimal Thickness { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and this query (`Properties.Resources.GetBoards`):

```sql
SELECT
  fixencoding(CODE) AS Code,
  fixencoding(DESC) AS Description,
  LNGT AS Length,
  WIDT AS Width,
  THCK AS Thickness,
  QNTY AS Quantity
FROM
  BOARDS
```

If the source uses the same system locale it's possible to use just `Encoding.Default.GetString(value)` instead of `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(value)`.